# c++/Qt: How to get a reference to database in the MainWindow class?

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite, qt-creator

In Qt-creator, I created SQLite database in a class called databaseManager, as follow:

```
QString DatabaseManager::open_db()
{
    QSqlDatabase db;
    QString path = "/Users/me/Documents/workspace/Muasaa/";
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(path+"Database v.1");
    if (db.open()){
        return "Database is created, open, and ready ...";
    } else {
        return db.lastError().text();
    }
}
```

Then I define the following in the header file of the MainWindow class:

```
Public:
   DatabaseManager *db_manager;
```

In the  source file, I call it as follow:

```
db_manager->open_db();
```

which creates and open the database.

However, I would like to use a reference to same database to use it in many functions in the MainWindow source file. How can I do that ?!

Answer (score 0):

Move the `QSqlDatabase db` variable into your class header, and add a method for getting it. As long as you create an instance of your `databaseManager` class and maintain a pointer to it in `MainWindow` you'll be able to retrieve it.

Comment: if I moved `QSqlDatabase db`  to the header file, the application exit with **_the program has unexpectedly finished_** !?

Answer (score 0):

QSqlDatabase::database() is a static function that returns a QSqlDatabase.
If you have more than one database, you have to provide a connection name in addDatabase() and in database()

Comment: I have only one database that I would like to use it in the MainWindow class. I want to display it in my GUI using QSqlTableModel.

Comment: In your MainWindow class use QSqlDatabase db =  QSqlDatabase::database(). This represents the database connected that you established with addDatabase(). I recommend reading the documentation and some example programs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a design solution may help?

Whatever your goal is, consider turning your DatabaseManager class into a [Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern). This way you'll be able to use your manager in all the gui classes.  Something like `DatabaseManager::instance()->your_method()`

Advantages:

- You are sure the connections are managed the right way
- Less oportunities for build problems

By the way, I'm not sure, but your program crash may be the result of using your db_manager pointer before it was initialized, in a slot maybe, or (more probable) it's an internal connection error. Have you checked the same connection attributes in a minimum possible example?

Comment: QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(...) and QSqlDatabase::database(...) are static functions, and if you study the documentation you will see that the internal list of database connections already is a singleton.